# Abrir Modal Popup à partir de outra pagina aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como faço pra abrir um Modal Popup extender a partir de outra pagina?

Estou usando um User Control para criar esse popup:

UserControl `ucModalInativar.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucModalInativar.ascx.cs" Inherits="Project.UserControls.ucModalInativar" %>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server" TargetControlID="">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Aspx `Consultar.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Consultar.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.ControleAcesso.LogAcesso.Consultar" Culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="Page" UICulture="auto" %>
....
<asp:Button ID="btnAbrir" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn azul margT20" runat="server" Text="Abrir Modal" />
....
```

Master Page `Site.Master`:

```
...
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <uc1:ucModalInativar runat="server" ID="ucModalInativar2" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
...
```

Sei que aquele `"TargetControlID"` tem que estar preenchido com algum componente da pagina, mas como ele é user control, ele está sendo implementado no Site.Master, e esse botão é de outra pagina.

**Como faço pra ao clicar no btnAbrir, o modal extender seja aberto?**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode expor se componente modal na `masterpage` como uma propriedade. Assim vc poderá acessar esse componente das páginas de conteúdo.

Olha esse link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xxwa0ff0(v=vs.100).aspx